# [modules RTC BridgeChannel.js e.onclose : Channel closed: 1006 - Jitsi Meet JVB

Tags: jitsi, jitsi-meet

I have installed jitsi Meet using below link on ubuntu 22.04

https://meetrix.io/blog/webrtc/jitsi/setup-%20install-jitsi-meet-jvb-on-ubuntu-20.html

Up to 2 participant its connecting audio and video , But after 3rd participant it is disconnecting audio and video , when any one removed from 3 , automatically connecting audio and video.

in browser console it shows

BridgeChannel.js:87 WebSocket connection to 'wss://meet.**domian.com/colibri-ws/default-id/376f2ff95d8ada38/319d2637?pwd=u38l9jh17sgk4pkdte6ikc9h0' failed:
_initWebSocket @ BridgeChannel.js:87
t @ BridgeChannel.js:106
Logger.js:154 2022-12-23T15:00:58.328Z [modules/RTC/BridgeChannel.js] <e.onclose>:  Channel closed by server

[image]

[image]

Comment: works w/ 2 person but not 3 means your p2p is enabled and working, but your setup is incomplete. Look at wss:// means your websocket connection is blocked. You need to check jvb.conf about websocket and make sure your firewall is not blocking.
You can try disable p2p and test with 2 person and find which part is blocking.
Similar to issue https://community.jitsi.org/t/websocket-connection-failed-channel-closed-1006/104124/41

Comment: Solution available 
UDP port was not enabled for external

https://community.jitsi.org/t/modules-rtc-bridgechannel-js-e-onclose-channel-closed-1006-jitsi-meet-jvb/119903/4